# non-deterministic connection success for recently started Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, paramiko

I am using the `googleapiclient` python api to start a vm, and then `paramiko` to connect to it via ssh.

I use `googleapiclient.discovery` to get the `GCE` api

```
compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
```

I start my vm using the [`start`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/python/latest/compute_v1.instances.html#start) api call

```
req  = compute.instances().start(project, zone, instance)
resp = request.execute()

while resp['status'] != 'DONE':
    time.sleep(1)
    resp = req.execute()
```

I then perform a [`get`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/python/latest/compute_v1.instances.html#get) request to find the vm details, and in turn the ephemeral external ip address

```
req  = compute.instances().get(project, zone, instance)
info = req.execute()

ip_address = info['networkInterfaces'][0]['accessConfigs'][0]['natIP']
```

Finally, I use `paramiko` to connect to this ip address.

```
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.connect(ip_address)
```

Non-deterministically, the `connect` call fails:

> ```
> .../lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 362, in connect
> raise NoValidConnectionsError(errors)
>
> paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnections Error: 
> [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
> ```

It seems to be timing related, as putting in a `time.sleep(5)` before the `ssh_client.connect` call has preventing this error.

I'm assuming this allows sufficient time for `sshd` to start accepting connections, but I'm not certain.

Putting sleeps in my code is uber hacky, so I'd much prefer to find a way to deterministically wait until the ssh daemon is running and available for me to connect to it (if that is indeed the cause of the `NoValidConnections` exception)

- Is there a way to instruct the GCE api to only return from `start` when the VM is running and `sshd` is available for me to connect to?
- Is there a way to request this information using the GCE api?

Alternately I see `paramiko` has a `timeout` option in the `connect` call - should I just change my 5 second sleep to a 5 second timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no way for GCE to know if the guest is SSH-able. (For instance, imagine a case where the guest uses a nonstandard method for allowing remote connections, so even checking `sshd` wouldn’t work. Even if you could rely on `sshd`, the way to check that it’s running depends on its version, host OS, configuration, etc.) GCE only knows hardware-level information about the VM, such as whether it rebooted.

To solve your problem, I would try the timeout mechanism in paramiko like you described, or maybe retry the connection attempt in a loop with a timeout since paramiko might not implement a full-state-reset retry internally (just speculating, I’m not sure).

Also, I think 5 seconds may be a little low — it’s probably fine for average response time, but outliers will be slower, which could cause your connection attempts to be flaky. Maybe bump that to 30 seconds or a minute just to be totally safe.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!